# Flutter fetch data from img src with html parse

Tags: html, flutter, parsing

[Html Codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q71se.png)

I have to get "<img src=" value. How can i do this?

I tried this :

```
responseBody = responseBody.substring(responseBody.indexOf('<img src=""'));
var lt = responseBody.substring(0, responseBody.indexOf('" />'));
```

and this :

```
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  print(document.getElementsByClassName("firma-isim")[i].getElementsByTagName("img")[0].getElementsByTagName("src").first;
}
```

But didn't work. Is there an easy way to do this? How can I do this?

Thanks.

HTML :

```
<div class="populer-firmalar">
    <span class="firma-sol" data-kaydir=".pop-firma,sol,1"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></span>
    <span class="firma-sag" data-kaydir=".pop-firma,sag,1"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>
    <div class="populer-firma-holder">
        <ul class="pop-firma">
                            <li class="active">
                <div class="firma-resim">
                    <a href="https://kimbufirma.com/firma/a3-dijital-web-tasarim-ve-yazilim-ajansi/"><img src="https://kimbufirma.com/firma/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/a3-dijital-web-tasarim-ve-yazilim-ajansi.cropped.270x200.jpg" alt="A3 DİJİTAL | WEB TASARIM VE YAZILIM AJANSI" width="270" height="200"></a>
                </div>
```

Comment: if so, whats wrong with: `document.getElementsByTagName('img').map((e) => e.attributes['src'])` ?

Comment: @pskink , i tried. Its return all of image links.   if i do this " print(document
          .getElementsByClassName("firma-isim")[i]
          .getElementsByTagName('img')
          .map((e) => e.attributes['src'])); "  return null.

Comment: @pskink , I getting the names of the companies.and each company has a picture. I'm trying to combine names and pictures.

Comment: thanks sir, someone answered in the comments, and it works.

Answer (score 6):

You can use html parser and html dom

```
var document = parse(body);
dom.Element link = document.querySelector('img');
String imageLink = link != null ? link.attributes['src'] : '';
```

Make sure to import these

```
import 'package:html/dom.dart' as dom;
import 'package:html/parser.dart' show parse;
```

Comment: it's returns null, sir.   " Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0 "

Comment: @GökhanVarış can you paste your html code so i can take a look? i can't copy it from a picture

Comment: I just tested it with your HTML and it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

I use Regular Expressions:

NetService:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http_parser/http_parser.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;


class NetService {
  /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
  static Future<T> getJson<T>(String url) {
    return http.get(Uri.parse(url))
      .then((response) {
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          return jsonDecode(response.body) as T;
        }
        print('Status Code : ${response.statusCode}...');
        return null;
      })
      .catchError((err) => print(err));
  }
  /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
  static Future<String> getRaw(String url) {
    return http.get(Uri.parse(url))
      .then((response) {
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          return response.body;
        }
        print('Status Code : ${response.statusCode}...');
        return null;
      })
      .catchError((err) => print(err));
  }
}
```

Main:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:_samples2/networking.dart';


const kUrl = 'https://kimbufirma.com/firma/';

var regExp = RegExp(r'<a href="[\w\d\:\.\-\/]+"><img src="([\w\d\:\.\-\/]+)"');

class WebSite {
  static Future<String> fetchWebPage () async {
    print('Start fetching...');
    return await NetService.getRaw(kUrl)
      .whenComplete(() => print('Fetching done!\n'));
  }
}

void main(List<String> args) async {
  var data = await WebSite.fetchWebPage();
  var images = regExp.allMatches(data).map((e) => e.group(1)).toList();

  // print(images);
  print(images.where((e) => e.contains('a3')));
  print(images[1]);
}
```

Result:

```
Start fetching...
Fetching done!

(https://kimbufirma.com/firma/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/a3-dijital-web-tasarim-ve-yazilim-ajansi.cropped.270x200.jpg)
https://kimbufirma.com/firma/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/a3-dijital-web-tasarim-ve-yazilim-ajansi.cropped.270x200.jpg
```

Comment: How can I get the regex address of the elements I want?

Comment: There is a lot of information about Regular Expressions on the Net, and you can practice it by using this [site](https://regex101.com/r/VCJK4s/1).